# Программа для создания простых MP3 файлов

Tags: библиотеки, mp3

Суть в том, что нужно написать программу, где можно будет создавать простые MP3 файлы, которые в последствии будут воспроизводится на телефоне. Параметры: частота, амплитуда, скважность. Импульсы должны быть прямоугольными, то бишь есть сигнал, нет сигнала. Может кто подсказать какие библиотеки можно использовать для реализации?

Comment: MP3 плохо годится для прямоугольных импульсов

Comment: А что тогда лучше выбрать?

Comment: Простой WAV, например? Он настолько простой, что его можно создавать даже без библиотек